# How to get button label from gtk_container_get_children

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have an array of buttons in my window and I would like to be able to click on any one of the buttons, call the button_clicked function and get the label of each button within the array.

I think I've managed to get the container of the buttons and in turn get the children within that container but I'm not sure how I would iterate through each button and thus get the labels.

Is there any way to do this?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void button_clicked(GtkButton *widget, gpointer data) {
  GtkWidget * parent = gtk_widget_get_parent((GtkWidget*)widget);
  GList *children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(parent));
  printf("%p\n", children->data);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *fixed;

  gchar *values[9] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
  char game_data[4] = "ZZ";
  GtkWidget *button[9];

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Tic Tac Toe");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

  fixed = gtk_fixed_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixed);

  for (int row = 0; row < 9; row+=3){
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++){

      button[row+column] = gtk_button_new_with_label(values[row+column]);
      gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), button[row+column], column*70, row*30);
      gtk_widget_set_size_request(button[row+column], 50, 50);
      g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button[row+column]), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(button_clicked), (gpointer)(game_data));

    }
  }

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
  G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uh, you *are* storing the button widget object references in the `button` array so no need to iterate the container to get them ...

Comment: So how would I get the labels of all the buttons inside button_clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, something like this:

```
static void button_clicked(GtkButton *widget, gpointer data)
{
  GtkWidget * const parent = gtk_widget_get_parent(GTK_WIDGET(widget));
  GList *children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(parent));
  for (const GList *iter = children; iter != NULL; iter = g_list_next(iter))
  {
    const GtkWidget * const lbl = gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(iter->data));
    const char * const text = gtk_label_get_text(GTK_LABEL(lbl));
    printf("'%s'\n", text);
  }
}
```

The point is that a button is a container, a bin to be more specific. So just ask the bin for its child, and assume that's the label.

Comment: @JohnSmith1234 I was just about to add a note that the above obviously was written on a non-GTK+ system and not at all tested, but ... it's a bit like riding a bike then. :)